# sftp uploads to multiple servers

Tags: amazon-ec2, sftp, multiple-instances

I have multiple EC2 instances that share the same directory and files in /var/www.

Now, everytime I need to upload, I need to use an sftp client, it is good maybe if I have only one server but, I would like to be able to transfer my changes to all the servers. I heard it can be done with unix sftp? But how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you upload to one instance, and they kick off, say, an rsync to get the files to the other ones?  If anything, you save on AWS transfer costs, as the network traffic on the rsync will be inside AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at LFTP. This should do the trick. You can set up multiple SFTP server connections and upload it.
You can also look here for the information: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1400704
There this was discussed.

Comment: can public keys be used with it? I don't see anything regarding them

Comment: That's not related with LFTP. LFTP just uses the connections and it will use your existing public keys.